# Relative Path or any way to access directory

Tags: java

I have images in one directory of a RCP application and I have to access that folder in any RCP application using relative path. How can I access it?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: what you have done, show some code

Comment: check this, might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294649/how-to-get-webcontext-path-in-struts/12294732#12294732

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you give the icon path starts with '/' that means it starts from your project directory else it will be relative to the class from where you are accessing this icon.